# virtualenv not activating the virtual enviroment

Tags: python, powershell, virtualenv

I have just started using `virtualenv` and don't have in-depth knowledge of it. I followed the instructions on the website and created the folder, and then executed the `activate.ps1` file. It executed without any errors, but when I tried using python, it was still using the python installed in my system and not the one in the virtual environment folder. Here are the commands I used:

```
PS A:\Code\IIITH\image-processing-iiith\SRIP> virtualenv venv
Using base prefix 'c:\\users\\shind\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37'
New python executable in A:\Code\IIITH\image-processing-iiith\SRIP\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
done.
PS A:\Code\IIITH\image-processing-iiith\SRIP> powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File venv\Scripts\activate.ps1
PS A:\Code\IIITH\image-processing-iiith\SRIP> python
Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> import sys
>>> os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
'C:\\Users\\shind\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37'
```

I used the `powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File venv\Scripts\activate.ps1` command for executing `activate.ps1` because executing it normally, I was getting some Security error. So, what am I doing wrong? The path of the executbale printed is the one in my system, when it should be of the executable inside the `venv` folder. Also, on `pip install` any packages, it says that requirement is satisfied. What should I do to activate the enviroment?

The error I get on normally executing the file is:

```
PS A:\Code\IIITH\image-processing-iiith\SRIP>  venv\Scripts\activate.ps1
venv\Scripts\activate.ps1 : File A:\Code\IIITH\image-processing-iiith\SRIP\venv\Scripts\activate.ps1 cannot be loaded
because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:2
+  venv\Scripts\activate.ps1
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

Comment: Don't call another powershell instance to run a file.. just call the script: `./venv/Scripts/Activate.ps1`

Comment: @ShantanuShinde, what version of Python are you using?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 it is giving me some security error. I mentioned that in the question description

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf Python 3.7.3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting up and using a virtual environment:

```
PS /> python -m venv .venv
PS /> Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force
PS /> ./.venv/Scripts/Activate.ps1
(.venv) PS /> pip install -r requirements.txt

[...]

(.venv) PS />
```

Comment: I followed this steps..
1. Move(cd - Change Directory) to project directory
2. Move(cd - Change Directory) to virtual environment folder created my PyCharm
3. Run Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force
4. .\Scripts\activate venv -- Then was able to activate virtual environment
Hope this helps someone..